# Joint image path with table column field to MySQL query PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, opencart, opencart2.x

I need to joint image root path with table column field. Here is my query which is not working. How I joint image path with "image"(name column in table) dynamic?

> SELECT id, image, LOAD_FILE( 'D:/wamp/www/path/image/' + image ) IS NOT NULL AS exist FROM product HAVING exist=1

My images are in D: drive path. MySQL query not concat using "+" sign in LOAD_FILE function.

If I use static path in query then it's working fine.

> SELECT id, image, LOAD_FILE('D:/wamp/www/path/image/catalog/image.jpg') IS NOT NULL as exist FROM product HAVING exist = 1

Thanks in advance. I need your help.

Comment: you need to use CONCAT

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT product_id ) AS total, LOAD_FILE( CONCAT('D:/wamp/www/path/image/', image)) IS NOT NULL AS exist FROM oc_product HAVING exist=1
```

May it will help you